# autocomplete in jsp page

Tags: jquery, hibernate, jsp

i want to extract data from the database rather local data while selecting value from the textarea. I used jquery-autocomplete.
Please tell me the site which provide a auto complete feature just like stack overflow for the tags at the ask question page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple example for JSP/JQuery:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html